# Make an if/in statement cleaner

Tags: python, if-statement

I am just starting to learn python right now and I came across this exercise.  I found a way to do it but I don't think that it's the best way.  This is what I have right now.

```
big_string = input("Enter a string of lowercase letters: ")


if "a" in big_string or "e" in big_string or "i" in big_string or "o" in big_string or "u" in big_string:
    print "Contains a lowercase vowel!"
else:
    print "Doesn't contain a lowercase vowel"
```

Is there a better way to do the if/in line?

Answer (score 2):

Without skipping straight to regexes, you could do:

```
if any(vowel in big_string for vowel in "aeiou"):
```

That said, it might be more expensive to scan a huge string five times than to do so once with a regex, so consider a regex here:

```
import re

...

if re.search(r'[aeiou]', big_string):
```

Comment: Note: On testing, with a `len` 20,001 string that contained the letter `o` in the middle, and no other vowels, or with no vowels at all, the `any` test was, surprisingly, *much* faster on my Python 3.5 x64 Linux install. It wasn't even close; the 4-5 `in` tests done by `any` (for with `o` and w/o vowel tests respectively) took 2.5 and 3.3 µs respectively, vs. the regex taking 37.5 and 73.5 µs respectively on the same inputs.

Comment: That said, both of them are _way_ faster than iterating `big_string` and testing for membership in the set of vowels. `any(let in 'aeiou' for let in big_string)` is 620 µs and 1.26 _ms_, and using a `set` doesn't help (the `O(1)` lookup doesn't matter for such small strings).

Comment: You could turn `big_string` into a `set` and get the `O(1)` lookup for `aeiou`. You would be swapping `5*O(n)` for `1*O(n) + 5*O(1)` but this would depend on the `O(n)` for set construction. [It makes me feel dirty using `O()` notation like this - I really do apologise :)]

Comment: @AChampion: Yeah, I checked on that. My `big_string` was only 11 unique characters aside from the `o` (if it existed), so dedupping shrunk it like crazy. It didn't help though; the total time for deduping + five containment tests was ~265 µs. Better than pathological iteration of `big_string`, but worse than all other options.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
if any((c in big_string) for c in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `any(x in b for x in a)` to determine if any of the items in list a are in list b.

In your case, you can do something like this:

```
if any(x in big_string for x in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
big_string = raw_input("Enter a string of lowercase letters: ")

chars = set('aeiou')

if any((c in chars) for c in big_string):
    print("Contains a lowercase vowel!")
else:
    print("Doesn't contain a lowercase vowel")
```

Comment: You really don't want to do it in this order; it's theoretically similar to iterating the vowels and checking `vowel in big_string` for each, but in practice, it's far slower (for len 20,000 `big_string` with a long gap before the first vowel, or no vowel at all, this takes ~300-400x longer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner for a slightly different kind if answer:

```
print("Contains a lowercase vowel!" if any(vowel in bigstring for vowel in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'])
      else "Doesn't contain a lowercase vowel")
```